# NStimer multiplies each time I reload view

Tags: timer, nstimer, invalidation

I have a one viewController which serves for 2 screens (main and settings)

in the view did load I have a timer that repeats unlimited times (checking condition)!

when I load setting screen and go back timer starts again but old timer works as well so after few load-unloads I have a lot of timers that checks same conditions (this makes my app to slow down).

I tried to use ***"invalidate"*** but it seams that my timer does not see it.(I put invalidate before I invoke timer and nullified it as well but without result)...

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using the same view controller for main and setting screen,both the times either main or settings

Solution is you initialise this timer in appdelegate and on switching the tabs main and settings first you invalidate it and after viewdidappear you start it again.

Answer (score 0):

call the **invalidate timer** in **viewWillDisappear** function

then it will remove the timer instance before it start the new reference.